# how do I access a radiobutton inside a ListBoxItem in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listboxitem

Please review the code for the ListBox I am using

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxDefaultAcc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" Height="410">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60" Width="450">
                            <RadioButton Content="{Binding}" GroupName="defaultAcc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="80" Width="450" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Now I want to access the `content` property of the `RadioButton` from codebehind.

The `ListBoxItems` are getting filled dynamically from the codebehind with the following code:

```
listBoxDefaultAcc.ItemsSource = from acc in db.Table<Accounts>()
                                        select acc.accName;
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: When do you want to access this and for which `RadioButton`? A side note, I don't think the `ListBoxItem` s are selectable with that ItemTemplate

Comment: I want to take the selected `RadioButton`'s content and store it in the isolated storage and if this `ItemTemplate` won't help then could you please suggest me the correct way to do it. Here is a screenshot of the GUI which gets generated with the above code. [link](http://img824.imageshack.us/i/capturejcf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the VisualTreeHelper and drill down to the control.  This is not recommended though.
Better is to only bind to the properties of the controls in you datatemplate and then retrieve the values by getting the binded values.   Technically in this case, if you would want to change the content of the radiobutton then you would need to change the item in the itemssource

Can you explain what you are trying to archieve by getting the content of the radiobutton?

Edit********************

```
  <ListBox Name="listBoxDefaultAcc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" Height="410">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60" Width="450">
                            <RadioButton Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" GroupName="defaultAcc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="80" Width="450" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

public partial class Home : Page
{
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var items = new List<SomeClass>();
        items.Add(new SomeClass() {Name = "a"});
        items.Add(new SomeClass() {Name = "b"});
        items.Add(new SomeClass() {Name = "c"});

        listBoxDefaultAcc.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    // Executes when the user navigates to this page.
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void testButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var items = (List<SomeClass>)listBoxDefaultAcc.ItemsSource;
        var selectedItem = items.Where(x => x.Selected).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    class SomeClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to store the `string` present in `content` property to the isolated storage in a text file.

Comment: Then why do you not just save the item you are binding to the content? Since it directly represents the content.

Comment: that depends on the user selection. Take a look at the screenshot [here](http://img824.imageshack.us/i/capturejcf.png) , now suppose the user click the `Personal Expense` RadioButton then I want the string `Personal Expense` to get stored in the file. hope i made myself clear to u

Comment: You should then do Bind the IsChecked property of the RadioButton to a boolean property of the item of your itemssource.  eg you have a class with 2 properties: Name and Selected.  Then you bind your itemssource to a collection of that class and bind the content properties to Name and the IsChecked propertie to Selected.  Then you can just query your collection and get the selected item.

Comment: Hey Luc, when I try to run this now, it throws an InvalidCastException on the line `var items=(List<Accounts>)listBoxDefaultAcc.ItemSource;` Please help me out with this.

Comment: Strange.  Try moving the nested class to outer scope and making it public.  If that doesn't help, you'll need to provide me with some more info (XAML ect.)

Comment: I dont have a nested class my `Accounts` class is a separate `.cs` file, so how would i change the scope of it and tell me what more info should I give you. The XAML code which I am using is present in my question.

Comment: If you set a brakepoint at the line, and select listBoxDefaultAcc.ItemSource and press alt + ctrl + q, then what type of value do you have in your Itemssource?

Comment: it shows `{System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIterator<Expense_Trackr.Accounts,string>}` in the value field for `listBoxDefaultAcc.ItemSource`

Comment: listBoxDefaultAcc.ItemsSource = (from acc in db.Table<Accounts>()
                                        select acc.accName).ToList();

Comment: adding the .ToList() and also editing the line `var items=(List<Accounts>)listBoxDefaultAcc.ItemSource;` to `var items = listBoxDefaultAcc.ItemSource.Cast<Accounts>();` helped me overcome the problem but now the same cast error comes in just the next line i.e. `var selectedItem = item.Where(x => x.selected).FirstOrDefault();` and the value field for `item` contains `{System.Linq.Enumerable.CastIterator<Expense_Trackr.Accounts>}`

Comment: Yes, these are internal classes that LINQ uses.  Only thing you need to do is assign the list and then get the item out like so:
// ASSIGN
(from acc in db.Table<Accounts>() select acc.accName).ToList(); 
//GET
 var items = (List<Accounts>)listBoxDefaultAcc.ItemsSource;
            var selectedItem = items.Where(x => x.Selected).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: I am doing the same thing but always getting the `InvalidCastException` ...stuck badly here now

Answer (score 1):

You should be using DataBinding. You should bind Content to a property, that represents content, of an object, you are setting as item.

This way, you dont have to care about ListBoxes or Templates or anything. You are simply manipulating objects, and theese changes get reflected in the GUI.