# How can get the value of Radio Button Inside Listbox Click on Button in Windows Phone Using C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

> I have Radio Group of Three Radio Button and a submit button also
>   inside of ListBox. I want to get the selected Radio Button Value from
>   the Radio Group on Button Click. Below my listbox item view. please
>   help me.

[image]

```
<ListBox x:Name="OptionListView" SelectionChanged="OptionListView_SelectionChanged" Height="720"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Background="#99000000" Width="480" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FeaturedQuestion}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    <RadioButton Content="Yes" GroupName="OpinionPoll" Foreground="White"/>
                                    <RadioButton Content="No" GroupName="OpinionPoll" Foreground="White"/>
                                    <RadioButton Content="Not Decide" GroupName="OpinionPoll" Foreground="White"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="btnSubmit" Click="btnSubmit_Click" Background="#d44740" Content="Submit" Style="{StaticResource TileButtonTemplate}" Height="65" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Foreground="White"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Comment: I think you'll need to read some book first. This is one of the most basic questions. Have you coded anything at all by yourself yet?

Comment: i know this is one of the basic questions. but Item is part of the listbox so i don't know how can i get the value of selected radio button on click on Submit button. If you know please let me.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with a listbox you need to have a List of something like a object.
This object represent your 3 radio button. For exemple you can work with an enum for get the checked value or create a custom radio button with 3 states.

Steps:
 - understand how to use and bind control inside listbox

- understand how to get the checked value (Exemple => `IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"`/>)

Comment: can you give me any tutorial Ref. or sample code. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply access the properties, by binding the `ListBox's` selected item.

Reference: [how do I access a radiobutton inside a ListBoxItem in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966713/)